# Multiplying matrixes without Numpy

Tags: python, matrix, algebra

I want to write a code which will multiply matrixes without using Numpy in Python. Unfortunately written function gives wrong result. Have an idea what is incorrect?

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6]]

B = [[1, 2], 
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]]

def MatrixMultiply(A, B):
    result = []
    for m in range(0, len(A) - 1): 
        rows = []
        for i in range(0, len(B[0]) - 1): 
            columns = 0
            for j in range (0, len(A)): 
                columns += A[m][j] * B[j][i]
            rows.append(columns) 
        result.append(rows) 
    return result

print(MatrixMultiply(A, B))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for j in range (0, len(A)):
```

should be

```
for j in range (0, len(B)):
```

and you should get rid of your `-1`s.